# How to access a method within a async function within a same class in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, class, methods, access-modifiers

I am trying to access MethodA within an async function inside MethodB, which is not accessible. But if i am trying outside async function it is working as expected. Below is the example.

**Options tried and not working:**

1. Used this.methodA()

```
class A{
constructor(){
}

async methodA(){
//Do something here
}

async methodB(){
await methodA(); //methodA is accessible in this line
await browser.getCurrentUrl().then(async function(){
await methodA(); //methodA is NOT accessible in this line
});
}
}

module.exports = new A(); //Using this to make the methods available in other places
```

Comment: Just like for non-async methods, you need to use `this.methodB()`

Comment: yes i tried but it was not working either.

Comment: As for calling `this.methodA()` from the `.then()` callback, you need to use an arrow function there as `this` won't refer to the class instance in the `function`. However you shouldn't be using `.then()` at all - just `const url = await browser.getCurrentUrl();` and then write `this.methodA()` in the next line like normal.

Comment: If that still doesn't work, please show us how you are calling `methodB`.

Comment: Btw, why are you exporting a `new A` instance instead of the class? If you want a singleton object, you shouldn't use `class` syntax but simply an object literal. Instead of trouble with `this`, you can then also refer to the object by its constant name.

Comment: Wonderful. Worked. I tried removing .then() and keep it await. (My bad - careless) - This worked. And also changing to arrow function worked. Both got me resolved.

Comment: @Bergi - Could you please direct me how to make use of what you are explaining in this  comment --> __"If you want a singleton object, you shouldn't use class syntax but simply an object literal."__

Comment: Just `module.exports.functionA = async function() { … }; module.exports.functionB = async function() { … };`. Or `module.exports = { async methodA() {…}, async methodB() { … } };`.

Comment: Thanks!! Got it!